# loop over files in python?

Tags: python

I have lots of files that I use glob.glob to sort them to plot. My files are ordered by number: lets say from file.00000 to file.99999.

I use:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('path/file.*'))
this_next = filenames 

for i, fname1 in enumerate(this_next):
    …
```

Now I would like to plot every 90 files.

Comment: Puzzled about the copy operation — why do you need both `filenames` and `this_next`?  The enumeration is a non-destructive operation.  Are you also after an index number (so you'd get `(1, 'file.00000')` and then `(91, 'file.00090')`, etc)?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler yes my files are eg. file1_0.00001, file_20.00001, ...

Comment: Hmmm; your question says '`file.00000` to `file.99999`'; your comment gives a different structure for the file names (`file1_0.00001`, `file20.00001`).  This is confusing to those trying to help you.  So, in your enumeration clause, what ends up in `i` and what ends up in `fname1`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I actually should say my files are (file_0.00001, ..., file_0.99999 and file_20.0001, ..., file_20.99999). In my first script I had to subtract to files from two directories, so I was using izip. I guess I just left it from that time. It should probably no need to keep both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, `glob` and `sorted` return lists, so in order to get one element every `90` you can use:

```
from glob import glob

for file in sorted(glob('path/file.*'))[::90]:
    ...
```

A more memory-efficient solution, if you are sure that glob returns sorted filenames would be to use generators:

```
from glob import iglob
from itertools import islice

for file in islice(iglob('path/file.*'), 0, None, 90):
    ...
```

But if you know that the pattern is that statis, for sure the most efficient way would be to generate the file names:

```
for file in ('file.%5d' % i for i in xrange(0, 99999, 90)):
    ...
```

Comment: So, It gave me syntax error for the first option. For second one should I use islice(iglob()) instead of sorted(glob.glob())

Comment: The first one works for me, which error do you get? The second only works if you are sure that your system returns data ordered.

Comment: filenames = sorted(glob.glob('/path/*.py_0.*')) [::90]:
                                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3527941 remove the `:`